# unable to access my external hard disk

Tags: hard-drive

while trying to open my external connected hard disk, I get:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/mani/My Passport1: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/mani/My Passport1"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to calculate free MFT records: Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details
```

.

please tell to resolve this issue. Also i dont want the data on the disk to be lost during the process.....
I'm using ubuntu 13.04 64bit on dell xpsM1530

Answer (score 1):

You need a Windows install to run CHKDSK C: /R on the volume. I do not think this can be done with Linux tools alone, correct me if I'm wrong... You can run from CLI or via GUI from the right click context menu (just right click volume C then look for tools.)

The process is non destructive to your data. I assume if you had RAID, you'd know. If after running CHKDSK, problem persists, suspect hardware failure (let's hope not.)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHKDSK